# Friendly resource recommendation for learning extended and typed first-order logics (and perhaps higher-order and non-classical logics)

Tags: logic, reference-request

Are there textbooks on extended and typed first-order logics that are a little more accessible to a "beginner" by being less mathematical? By "less mathematical", I mean doesn't approach the material by using (at least explicitly) mathematical axioms, proofs and theorems. An example is http://intrologic.stanford.edu/public/lessons.php. A counterexample, ie a "more mathematical" example, would be Mathematical Logic by Heinz-Dieter Ebbinghaus, Jörg Flum etc.

By extended and typed first-order logics, I mean the kind of content I need to understand:
https://www.tptp.org/Seminars/TPTPWorldTutorial/LogicTFF.html
https://www.tptp.org/Seminars/TPTPWorldTutorial/LogicTX0.html

By extension, it would be a bonus if you can recommend "less mathematical" material on typed higher-order and non-classical logics as well, so I can understand:
https://www.tptp.org/Seminars/TPTPWorldTutorial/LogicTHF.html
https://www.tptp.org/Seminars/TPTPWorldTutorial/LogicNTF.html

Comment: Graham Priest, [An Introduction to Non-Classical Logic (Cambridge UP, 2nd ed. 2008)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Non_Classical_Logic/Q88xngEACAAJ) and Richard Zach, [Sets Logic Computation. An Open Introduction to Metalogic (2019)](https://slc.openlogicproject.org/)

Comment: For Type Theory, it is more difficult... William Farmer, [Simple Type Theory. A Practical Logic for Expressing and Reasoning About Mathematical Ideas (2023, Springer)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Simple_Type_Theory/VfOkEAAAQBAJ)